# What's the meaning of "roll over" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.neoseeker.com/mario-tennis-gba/faqs/119536-mario-tennis-pt-neo14789.html)

> This is why your character is still on the bed, oblivious to
>   the world.  After you **roll over**, you are greeted again, then your partner cleans up your room a bit.

No meaning of roll over correctly matches with this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 64. [roll over](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/roll--over)
>       c. to turn over:

Essentially, it means to roll or turn from facing one way to facing another way (usually the opposite direction).
[image]

I think in general it would mean to roll/turn from position 1 to position 4.

Here is the [actual clip](https://youtu.be/deCH47siFVw?t=160) of what happens. Notice that the character does in fact turn from facing left to facing right—almost. :)

Comment: A dog usually rolls over as part of a trick. The quote seems to be talking about a person who is reluctant to get out of bed for some reason. Physically, the movements are similar, but I still think this picture is a mismatch for the quote.